# Dividir en varios df a partir de la columna "Año"

Tags: python, pandas, bucles, dataframe

¿Se puede resolver a a partir de un ciclo?
que el `df` se divida en varios `df`, todos los renglones con año 2018 se vayan al mismo `df`, los del 2019 a otro y así sucesivamente.

Ejemplo:

| año | ingresos | perdidas |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018 | 100 | 50 |
| 2018 | 20 | 20 |
| 2019 | 30 | 79 |
| 2020 | 104 | 36 |
| . | . | . |
| 2022 | 120 | 40 |

Comment: Lo menos que debes hacer cuando trabajas xon pandas es usar bucles. ¿Por que no filtras los datos?

Comment: hola, la columna de años, contiene años desde el 2012 hasta el 2020. ¿te refieres a filtrar los datos de la forma : df[df['años'] = xaño ] repetirlo 9 veces? o ¿de que forma los filtrarias? saludos.

Comment: Pues si, esa sería la forma de filtrarlos. Además, es necesario tener 9 dataframes distintos? Que tienes que hacer después de separarlos?

Answer (score 0):

Separar en 9 dataframes no es complejo, pero ¿qué variables almacenarían esos 9 resultados? Hay dos posibilidades sencillas:

- Guardar los 9 dataframes resultantes en una lista. Así, si esa lista se llama `resultados` tendrías que `resultados[0]` es el dataframe correspondiente a 2012, `resultados[1]` el de 2013, y así sucesivamente.
- Guardarlos en un diccionario de modo que la clave sea el año y el valor sea el dataframe. De este modo podrías acceder a `resultados[2012]` para obtener el dataframe de ese año.

Personalmente encuentro más legible y útil la segunda opción, de modo que esta sería mi solución:

```py
resultados = {}  # Diccionario inicialmente vacío
for año in range(2012, 2021):
  resultados[año] = df[df.años == año]
```

Una vez completada la extracción puedes usar el resultado accediendo a un año concreto (`resultados[2019]` por ejemplo), o iterar por todos los resultados usando el método `.items()` de los diccionarios, por ejemplo así:

```
for año, dataframe in resultados.items():
  print(f"Dataframe correspondiente a {año}")
  print("----------------------------------")
  print(dataframe)
```

### Ampliación

Si no sabes de antemano qué años están presentes en `df`, puedes usar `df.años.unique()` para obtenerlos. Entonces el bucle de separación por años podría ser así:

```
resultados = {}  # Diccionario inicialmente vacío
for año in df.años.unique():
  resultados[año] = df[df.años == año]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo no usaría bucles (por que pandas tiene formas más rápidas de hacer las cosas) ni filtros (que supongo que implica varios recorridos al DataFrame). Lo mejor que se me ocurre es usar el método [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), que devuelve un objeto [GroupBy](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/groupby.html). El método groupby justamente crea un objeto que nos permite separar en varios DataFrames utilizando, por ejemplo, el valor de una o más columnas.

```
groups = df.groupby("año")

# Obtengo un grupo especifico en forma de DataFrame
print(groups.get_group(2019))

# Itero sobre las keys del diccionario devuelto por groups.groups
# Y obtengo el DataFrame segun el nombre del grupo.
for group in groups.groups:
    print(groups.get_group(group))
```

Te recomiendo leer la documentación que enlacé para entender mejor como trabajar con los objetos GroupBy y conocer todo lo que ofrecen.